# Where are the Build Folders in XCode 5.02?

Tags: xcode, macos

I've created a projects for a KEXT using XCode 5.02. Let's say my project name is MyKext. The build folders for debug and release should be MyKext/Build/Debug and MyKext/Build/Release respectively.

I can build and clean the project successfully. However, if I build, the Build folders are nowhere to be found.

I use the default Build Locations settings for the project. So, can someone tell me what I need to do to locate the build folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are normally at Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: Not in this case. All Library/Developer has in it are Acknowledgement.pdf and Acknowledgement.rtf. Again, the preferences (and related Apple documentation) say the build folder should be nested under the project's parent folder.